# How to add or update context root of tomcat server in Intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am setting up my project in Intellij for which I was following companies documentation but the problem is its written for eclipse IDE. In the documentation they asked to "Update the Context root under -> WebProject Settings : order/genome-database"

I don't know how to do the same in Intellij. I added tomcat server and added artifacts to it. Its running fine without errors and lunching the application but its not working as expected. Now, I want to update "context root" of tomcat server and I don't know how to do it for Intellij.

I was googling for a while but couldn't resolve the issue. Please let me know if you know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that correctly you set up your Tomcat Server in intellij IDEA you should have 5 tabs in the tomcat configuration: Server, Deployment, Logs, Code Coverage and Startup/Connection. In the deployment tab you can change the application context, I hope that is what you/they meant.
[image]

Comment: I did that but its not working as expected. My application launches and then stuck at the first page itself. I guess I need to check application settings in depth. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

File ->Project Structure -> Artifacts ->  and check if there are war files from previous ones.

Also, delete if you have previous deployments in the Tomcat server and add a new one.